# Combining 2-D plots for different values of a parameter into 3-D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

So I have a system of non-linear differential equations that depend on a parameter $ \mu $. What I'm trying to do is take the 2-D phase portraits for different values of $ \mu $ and combine them into a 3-D plot with $\mu $ on the 3rd axis. The range of $ \mu$ that I need is $ (-2,4) $. The problem is that I have no idea how to go about it.

[[image: <span class=]$ \mu =-1 $" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKv0J.png)

[[image: <span class=]$ \mu =0 $" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c82XJ.png)

[[image: <span class=]$ \mu =1 $" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlZTg.png)

Generation of phase portrait for a specific value of $\mu$

````
\[Mu] = 1;
eqn1 = x'[t] - y[t] + x[t] ((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2 - \[Mu]) == 0;
eqn2 = y'[t] + x[t] + y[t] ((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2 - \[Mu]) == 0;
eqn3 = x[0] == .01;
eqn4 = y[0] == .01;
sol = NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 PlotLabel -> "\[Mu] = 1"]```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[x, y, μ, pndsv]
pndsv = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4},
  {x[t], y[t], μ}, {t, 0, 100}, {μ}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[pndsv[i], {i, -2, 4, 1}]], {t, 0, 100}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, PlotPoints -> 300, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, Range[-2, 4, 1], LegendLabel -> Style["μ", 16]]]
```

[image]